# text increase <li> limit

Tags: html, css

text in my menu (Superfish menu) increase limit, I add some css (width,height) but not work :

[image]

i use overflow-wrap: break-word but not work !

html code:

```
 <div class="menu-menu2-container">
                <ul id="menu-menu2" class="sf-menu">
                    <li id="menu-item-1769" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-1769">
                        <a href="#">AGMA QUI SOMMES NOUS?</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li id="menu-item-1775" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1775">
                                <a href="#">le mot du président</a>
                            </li>
                            <li id="menu-item-1778" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-1778">
                                <a href="#">Finances et actionnaires</a>
                                <ul class="sub-menu">
                                    <li id="menu-item-1779" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1779">
                                        <a href="#">Nos chiffres clés</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li id="menu-item-1780" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-1780">
                                <a href="#">Le Systeme de Management de la Qualite</a>
                                <ul class="sub-menu">
                                    <li id="menu-item-1781" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1781">
                                        <a href="#">Certification</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li id="menu-item-1782" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1782">
                                        <a href="#">Politique Qualité</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li id="menu-item-1770" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1770">
                        <a href="#">ASSURANCE ENTREPRISES</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: Add your css to the code snippet

Comment: do you want the text ellipsis when it longer then blue section

Comment: add you css please

Comment: #menu-menu2 >li>a{
    
 width: 180px;
    height: 64px;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
 } 

   #menu-menu2>li>ul{
    margin-top: 0px;
   
}

Comment: not i want the text back to the line if the space is not enough

Comment: show all your css in snipet

Comment: i'm using superfish Menu https://superfish.joelbirch.co/examples/ , i cannot past all the css its too large to past !

Comment: Try with `white-space:pre`;

Comment: i want the menu be like this : http://www2.0zz0.com/2018/08/15/12/769410353.png

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#menu-menu2 > li {
    word-break: break-word; 
}
#menu-menu2 > li > a {
    width: 180px;
    height: 64px;
    word-break: break-word; 
}
```

EDIT:

```
#menu-menu2 > li {
    width: 180px;
    height: 64px;
    word-break: break-word;
}
#menu-menu2 > li > a {
    text-decoration: none; /* no width or height given */
}
```

Hope I pushed you further.

Comment: aah ok my bad. A question: did you give the `#menu-menu2 > li` a width ?

Comment: after added      white-space: normal;  it work thanks !

Comment: i think its by default set to normal. Glad you finally made it.